# how should i set my current location in maps as my start point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm a beginner for ios development. What I need is im set my start point as my current location?

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f,   372.0f)];
    self.view = contentView;


    routeMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.frame];
    routeMapView.delegate = self;
    routeMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [contentView addSubview:routeMapView];



    routeOverlayView = [[UICRouteOverlayMapView alloc] initWithMapView:routeMapView];

    diretions = [UICGDirections sharedDirections];
    diretions.delegate = self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D sOri,sDest;



    startPoint=@"";
    endPoint= @"34 Jalan Yew, 55100 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia";

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question and tell what results you expected?

Comment: explain your question clearly.

Comment: greeting guys,i want to route from my start point to my destination point.i have my destination point as above(endpoint).now my StartPoint will be my current location.How should i get the current location in my start point @""?

Comment: Use CLLocationManager. CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

Answer (score 0):

You can find the doc of MKMapView [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView).
**Manipulating the Visible Portion of the Map** part is what you're looking for.